# How to delete the gaps & reset the auto_increment value in mysql

Tags: mysql

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2hd2ush&s=8#.U7vlf_mSzNg

I created the table which have auto_increment in id field, when i delete some row & insert another row it having a gaps between them. For example id is 1,2,3,4,5. Deleted 3,5 and insert another row, the id will be 1,2,4,6, it should be 1,2,3,4,5. Please help.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or you always want it with 'no gaps'?

Comment: That behaviour is normal **and desired**. You don't want to "reset" auto_increment counter, its job is not to provide you with nice, sequential numbers.

Comment: Possible [dublicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/)

Comment: I would have to agree with N.B. but if you tell us why this is what you want, we might be able to give a pointer in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour is normal and desired. You don't want to "reset" auto_increment counter, its job is not to provide you with nice, sequential numbers.

Thanks for the clarify N.B